# moc command not found?

Tags: compiling, path, c++, qt

On my Gentoo systems I've never had a problem with this and I run `moc` as I run any other command in the terminal.  I recently switch to Fedora 15/16 and notice that running `moc` doesn't work.  I get `bash: moc: command not found...`.  Instead, I have to give its full path, `/usr/lib64/qt4/bin/moc`.

1. I would like to know why the Fedora folks have not set this up so calling `moc` just works without giving its full path (or, perhaps I've done something to break?)
2. As I'm very new to non-Gentoo systems, I would like to know of a universal way to call `moc` so that it works on any *nix system.

Comment: It could be helpful to know, than `media-sound/moc` package is running by `mocp` command.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to run application without specifying whole path to it, directory where executable is installed must be in `$PATH` variable. You can check what is in `$PATH` by using `echo $PATH`. To modify `$PATH` you can use `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64/qt4/bin/`. After that you can use just `moc` to start it. To make changes permanent you may put that line to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: I know all that!  I'm trying to write scripts that will work on any *nix system, and my scripts call `moc`.  If running `moc` doesn't work eventhough it's installed, how would I make sure my scripts work?

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility I guest, in my case I was having This problem in a laptop with Debian Jessie, the right thing was :

```
aptitude install qt4-qtconfig
```

> user@host$ moc
>
> moc: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/moc': No such file or directory

According to /usr/share/doc/moc/README.Debian we need to run:

```
user@host$mocp
```

in addition to that you can also use themes and make your own configuration file in your  >.moc directory, you can use alias in your .bashrc

```
alias moc='mocp -T yourtheme '
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I would like to know why the Fedora folks have not set this up so calling moc just works without giving its full path (or, perhaps I've done something to break?)

This should be for backward compatibility with Qt3.

> 2) As I'm very new to non-Gentoo systems, I would like to know of a universal way to call moc so that it works on any *nix system.

You may use `pkg-config` :

```
pkg-config --variable=moc_location QtCore
```